# How do I schedule tweets in a TweetDeck?

Tags: tweetdeck

How do I schedule sweets in a TweetDeck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to Schedule Tweets in TweetDeck for Desktops](http://compixels.com/290/how-to-schedule-tweets-in-tweetdeck-for-desktops)

> The new scheduled tweets feature is very useful for a power tweeter who want to feed followers with content round the clock. So, how to schedule tweets in TweetDeck? We have the answer